# Converting C Byte Array To TFLite File

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, tflite

I have a C Byte Array of model. Is it possible to generate the .Tflite file back from the C Byte array. If it is possible then help me with it.

I just need to convert the C Byte array to Tflite model. Is there any tool or command help me with them. Thank You.

Comment: It is possible to convert tflite model into C Byte array. But, what are you trying to do with it? Please give a context.

Comment: No I just asking how to convert C Byte array to Tflite model not the vice versa. I just downloaded a c byte array model but I am just need to get the tflite model of that C Byte array. Is there any other tool for it or any ways to do it?

Comment: Hi @Sweeton, thank you for clarifying. Can you share the link to the C byte array? Which format is it in?